# Windows FTP Folder on Desktop

Tags: windows, ftp, desktop

I saw this before but I looked everywhere and cant find a tutorial or anything anywhere.

I have a server and what I want to do is have a folder on my desktop where when i open it or if i where to browse and see the folder, if i open it it'll go to my ftp and allow me to grab files from my server or save files in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to "My Network Places", then you can add an FTP connection there, and then create a shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Fling](http://www.nchsoftware.com/ftp/index.html)

Files dropped on your desktop are automatically uploaded to the server.  For the other direction, you can quickly open an explorer window.  Works great.